# Sending email with cc and bcc

Tags: trigger, email-template, process-builder, email-alert, singleemailmessage

I am creating an email alert and a email VF template. I see no option to put cc / bcc in the email alert. It is just recipient's address. I am planning to use a process builder to support sending emails. What are my options here? Is it even possible to put cc and bcc in email alerts? or do I have to go with writing a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email Alerts do not permit specification of cc: or bcc:

If this is important to you , you will need to use Apex outbound email classes and methods - but be cognizant that there are fairly restrictive limits on the number of outbound Apex emails you can send per day per org.

Comment: Do you know what is the limit for sending emails for an unlimited org

Comment: The daily limit for emails sent through email alerts is 1,000 per standard Salesforce license per org—except for free Developer Edition and trial orgs, where the daily workflow email limit is 15 . The overall org limit is 2,000,000. This limit applies to emails sent through email alerts in workflow rules, approval processes, flows, processes, or the REST API.

Comment: @SfdcBat - consult https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm